# SSIS derived Column (DateKey)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am trying to create a derived column that will convert the date into a date keys, apparently, I got the expression right but when I run the package and go to my destination table I don't see my derived column created. I am not sure what could be the error, please help!
[image]

Comment: You create a column in database table, then you map your derived column to that column. I am not sure if it is 'created' automatically. You'll have to map it like TransactionNbr.

Comment: Surrogatekeys Should not have a mapping. They should be found via lookups in your dimensions. And having an derived column with -1 as value if there is no match

Comment: Furthermore try to look at your setup. Your destination is clearly a fact-table with a measure and some Keys to dimensions. Your source is some kind of businesslogic, but doesnt even meet the requirements to your fact table except your measure. Add the DateKey dimension to your fact. And lookup the rest of your keys in lookups. Make sure the businesskeys is in your source script also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Issue

You create a derived column, but you didn't maped it to a destination column (it doesn't create a column automatically in the OLEDB Destination)

[image]

So you have to create a new column in the destination table, and Map the derived column to it like shown in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

From the mapping image, it is clear that you haven't mapped it. Ideal steps are:

1. Create a new column in database.table
2. Write the expression for derived column.
3. **Map** the derived column with one created in db.